# Proving existence and uniqueness of a function $f':\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, relations

Suppose $A$ is a group with operation $\times$.

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$ be a function where, for any natural number $m,n$

$f(m+n)=f(m)\times f(n)$

We want to show that this can be extended to a function $f':\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ where, for any integer $m,n$

$f'(m+n)=f'(m)\times f'(n)$

Show that such a $f'$ exists and that it is unique.

So far, I have $f'(n)=f(n)$ when $n>0$ and $f'(n)=1$ (identity) when $n=0$ and $f'(n)=f(-n)^{-1}$ for $n<0$

Does this function work, if not, whats missing?
How do I demonstrate that the function i defined works and that its unique?

Comment: Well, you haven't defined it on the negative numbers, that's what is missing. You need to say what $f'(-n)$ will be when $n\gt 0$. Then you need to show that if $g$ is any function on $\mathbb{Z}$ that "works" and which agrees with $f$ on $\mathbb{N}$, then it must actually be equal to $f'$.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, fixed!

Comment: Well, now you need to check if it works; you already know that $f(n+m)=f(n)f(m)$ when $n$ and $m$ are positive, so you need to consider the case where they are both negative, one is positive and the other negative, one is positive and the other zero, etc.

Comment: Was this change of group $A$ to $G$ intentional?

Comment: Oh sorry, no that was a mistake. I was looking at a question SE suggested and they had $G$, let me fix that

Comment: You can plug $m=n=0$ and use group property of cancellation to show $f(0)=e$ where $e$ is the identity element of the group.

Comment: I don't understand what's being discussed here. Even if only $f(1)=a\in A$ is known, there exists exactly one homomorphism $f':\mathbb{Z}\to A$ such that $f'(1)=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function works!

I'll omit the $\times$. And, as you used, $1 \in A$ will be the neutral element of the group $A$.

To see that it works we just need to do a case analysis.

**Case $\boldsymbol{n>0}$ and $\boldsymbol{m>0}$:** $$f'(n+m)=f(n+m)=f(n)f(m)=f'(n)f'(m).$$

**Case $\boldsymbol{n=0}$ and $\boldsymbol{m\in \mathbb{Z}}$:** $$f'(0+m)=f'(m)=f'(0)f'(m).$$

**Case $\boldsymbol{n<0}$ and $\boldsymbol{m<0}$:** $$f'(n+m)=f(-n-m)^{-1} = f(-m-n)^{-1} = (f(-m)f(-n))^{-1} =f(n)^{-1}f(m)^{-1}=f'(n)f'(m).$$

**Case $\boldsymbol{n>0}$ and $\boldsymbol{m<0}$:**

For that we will actually need to separate into 3 subcases. We will also use that $f'(n)=(f'(-n))^{-1}$.

**Subcase $\boldsymbol{n+m>0}$:** $$f'(n)=f'(n-m+m)=f'(n+m)f'(-m)=f(n+m)f(-m)=f'(n+m)f'(m)^{-1},$$
that is, $$f'(n+m)=f'(n)f'(m)$$

**Subcase $\boldsymbol{n+m=0}$:** $$f'(n) = f'(n+m-m) = f'(n+m)f'(-m) = f'(n+m) f(-m) = f'(n+m)f'(m)^{-1},$$
that is, $$f'(n+m)=f'(n)f'(m)$$

**Subcase $\boldsymbol{n+m<0}$:**
see that $f'(n+m) = f'(-m-n)^{-1}$ and that $-n-m>0$, then we can use first subcase so that
$$f'(n+m) = f'(-n-m)^{-1} = (f'(-m)f'(-n))^{-1} = f'(-n)^{-1}f'(-m)^{-1} = f'(n) f'(m).$$

And that covers every possible pair of integers $n,m$.

To see that it is unique, consider any function $g:\mathbb{Z} \to A$ such that $g(n)=f(n)$ for every $n>0$ and
$$g(n+m)=g(n)g(m)$$
for every $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Then, putting $n=m=0$, we have
$$g(0+0)=g(0)g(0) \implies g(0)=g(0)^2 \implies g(0)=1.$$

Moreover, let $n<0$ then using that $g(-n)=f(-n)$ and $g(0)=1$ we have
$$g(n-n)=g(n)g(-n) \implies 1 = g(n)f(-n) \implies g(n)=f(-n)^{-1}.$$

And that is exactly how you defined $f'$. So $g=f'$.

Comment: Arturo Magidin commented the case " one is positive and the other negative", why don't we need it in this case?

Comment: Oh, does "Case $n,m>0$" mean $n>0$ or $m>0$? In that case, how do we know $f'(n+m)=f(n+m)$? Couldn't the negative number of the two have a greater absolute value making the sum negative overall?

Comment: @SamuelS. Sorry, I completely missed that case $n>0$ and $m<0$. I edited it now.
And yes, $n,m>0$ means $n>0$ and $m>0$. In this case $n+m>0$, then, by definition, $$f'(n+m)=f(n+m).$$
I believe you mixed up the cases in your last comment. Maybe you were referring to the case $n>0$ and $m<0$, which is now added to the answer.